# ¿Como desactivo una version anterior en Play Console?

Tags: google-play-console

Tengo mi app subida en la versión 2.6.0 y me aparece que también la versión 1.0.6 está activa también.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como puedo desactivar o quitar esa versión?